# C# ASP.NET Input field for Price gives ValidationMessage that the field must be a number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application I have a form where a user can create a new part.

The form for creating the part contains basic things like ID, Name, Description etc. However I am having some trouble with the `Price` field.

The `Price` field is set to a decimal:

```
[Table("pricelist")]
public class Pricelist
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Price_id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AdminDescription { get; set; }
    public string AdminDescriptionShort { get; set; }
    public string Standard { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

But when I type in a value like 50,12, it gives me a ValidationMessage that sais: `"The field Price must be a number."`

It does not give me an Error however.

Here is the form field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Prijs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

What I find weird is that it does work in another form.

Other form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Prijs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried setting it to a float before but that did not work out.
I don't think the Error from this attempt to fix it matters since I found out that what goes wrong in one form, works in the other form.

Comment: What is the culture on your server And are you getting this as a client side message (in which case you need to reconfigure the `$.validator` to accepts numbers with the comma as a decimal separator

Comment: @StephenMuecke The culture of the server is Neutral and the messige is client side. But it works in the second form with a comma, just not in the first form.

Comment: Even if you reconfigure the validation as per the dupe, you still going to need to set the server culture to one that accepts numbers with a comma as the decimal separator (or create a custom ModelBinder) otherwise a server side error will occur